# Get Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView Selected Text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use `Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView` in my ASP.NET usercontrol, I know this control is obsolete, but for some reasons I can't change it, and I need to get the selected node text by javascript, I can get the selected index:

```
function GetSelectedNodeText()
{
  var TreeNodeObj = document.getElementById("mytreenodeId");
  var selectednodeIndex = TreeNodeObj.selectedNodeIndex;
}
```

But I can't get the text of selected node. does any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetSelectedNodeText()
{    
    var tree = document.getElementById("myTreeId");
    var treeNode = tree.getTreeNode(tree.selectedNodeIndex);
    alert(treeNode.getAttribute("text"));
}
```